# How to move window after countdown is done?

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I created one countdown with php and javascript. I have three files test.php, mentenanta.php and response.php and it works fine, but when the countdown finishes, I want to come back to index.php automatically. Here are my files:

**test.php**

```
<?php
    $_SESSION["duration"] = $mentenanta[0]['finish_time'];
    $_SESSION["start_time"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $end_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["duration"].'minutes', strtotime($_SESSION["start_time"])));
    $_SESSION["end_time"] = $end_time;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location="mentenanta.php";
</script>
```

Here is the **mentenanta.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<div id="response"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval(function()
{
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
},1000)

</script>
```

And Here is **response.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();

$from_time1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1 = $_SESSION["end_time"];

$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond=strtotime($to_time1);

$differenceinseconds=$timesecond-$timefirst;

if($timesecond > $timefirst){
    echo gmdate("H:i:s", $differenceinseconds); 
}
?>
```

It works fine, but I don't know how to set to automatically move header when the timer finishes to index.php or another files, and of course to set the XmlHttpsRequest.abort() to stop it.

Comment: you can use setTimeout function javascript after timeout you directly redirect to require page

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda ok, but how long to tell him to give him timeout?